# pam_tally2 tallying successful logins as failures

Tags: linux, debian, pam

I am editing my /etc/pam.d/common-auth file in debian to the following:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_succeed_if.so user = linuxuser
auth    required                        pam_tally2.so file=/var/log/faillog onerr=fail deny=3 unlock_time=30
account required                        pam_tally2.so
```

so I can enable account lockouts for failed password attempts. When testing with the account `user`, it tallies both successful and unsuccessful logins

In my research I found two suggestions.

1) Add `account required            pam_tally2.so` to /etc/pam.d/common-account

2) Make sure /etc/ssh/sshd_config had `ChallengeResponseAuthentication no` instead of `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes`

I have made both of these changes, and am still having this problem. I also tried rearranging the lines so that it looked like the following:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_succeed_if.so user = linuxuser
auth    required                        pam_tally2.so file=/var/log/faillog onerr=fail deny=3 unlock_time=30
account required                        pam_tally2.so
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
```

But this did not work either. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I have now noticed that when logging in as `user` the tally is incremented before the password is entered and does not get reset if the correct password is entered. I now have the pam_tally2 rules placed about pam_unix.so and the `account required     pam_tally2.so` in both the common-auth and common-account files.  HELP!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to provide the faillog file to both the tally and the reset line. The following is what works:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_succeed_if.so user = linuxuser
auth    required                        pam_tally2.so file=/var/log/faillog onerr=fail deny=3 unlock_time=30
account required                        pam_tally2.so file=/var/log/faillog
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `pam_tally2` is counting the number of accessing attempts. So if its a successful or unsuccessful attempt `pam_tally2` count will get incremented. We can use `pam_acct_mgmt` or `pam_setcred` call after `pam_authenticate` to reset the counter value.

Comment: where is this `pam_authenticate` supposed to be ? on my Ubuntu 18.04 it is never used